# How to query records

Tags: soql

In Account object I have 1000 records.i need to query first 100 records,next i need to query after 101 records.how it is possible.my first query is like that

[select id,name from Account LIMIt 100];

i want query like this[select id,name from Account LIMIT 101];

Comment: why would you want to make multiple queries? It will count towards your governor limits. Isn't it better to just query them all at once and then split it in apex if you really need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Use OFFSET**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm)

> When expecting many records in a query’s results, you can display the
>   results in multiple pages by using the OFFSET clause on a SOQL query.
>   For example, you can use OFFSET to display records 51 to 75 and then
>   jump to displaying records 301 to 350. Using OFFSET is an efficient
>   way to handle large results sets.
>
> Use OFFSET to specify the starting row offset into the result set
>   returned by your query. Because the offset calculation is done on the
>   server and only the result subset is returned, using OFFSET is more
>   efficient than retrieving the full result set and then filtering the
>   results locally. OFFSET is available in API version 24.0 and later.

```
[select id,name from Account LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100 ];
```

this will return all the records except starting 100 records

you need to query like [select id,name from Account OFFSET 100 LIMIT 100];

> each time you need to increase OFFSET value like to get the first 100
>   use offset = 0 and limit 100, this will return first 1-100 records.
>
> 2nd time set OFFSET 100 and limit 100 this will return 101 to 200
>   records.
>
> 3rd time set OFFSET 200 and limit 100 this will return 201 to 300
>   records ...
>
> this way you can use till 2000 records but after that you can't
>   because OFFSET have limit of 2K. We can use more than 2k value in
>   OFFSET

Comment: This not a vf page....just i need to query first 100 records..after that 101-200

Comment: @Hemalathaparuchuri yeah you need to query like `[select id,name from Account OFFSET 100 LIMIT 100];` each time you need to increase OFFSET value like to get the first 100 use offset = 0 and limit 100, this will return first 1-100 records. second time set OFFSET 100 and limit 100 this will return 101 to 200 records. 3rd time set OFFSET 200 and limit 100 this will return 201 to 300 records ... this way you can use till 2000 records but after that you can't because OFFSET have limit of 2K. We can use more than 2k value in OFFSET

Comment: @Ratan Why don't you update this in your answer.

Comment: First Limit must come and then Offset @Ratan, Otherwise it won't query the records...

Comment: @Ratan select id,name from Account OFFSET 50 LIMIT 100 iquery like this but it shows error(Unknown error parsing query)

Comment: @Hemalathaparuchuri ahh just change the order of limit and OFFset `select id,name from Account  LIMIT 100  OFFSET 50`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Queries with Offset and Limit

Syntax to use *Limit* with *Offset* to retrieve records is following:

> SELECT *fieldList* FROM *objectType*
>
> [WHERE *conditionExpression*]
>
> ORDER BY
> *fieldOrderByList*
>
> LIMIT *numberOfRowsToReturn*
>
> OFFSET *numberOfRowsToSkip*

If you want to query the First 100 Records give the query like below.

```
Select ID, Name from Account LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

If you want to query the next 100 Records give the query like below.

```
Select ID, Name from Account LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100
```

Hope this might helps...

Comment: In second SOQL Offset will be 100 to start from 101.

Comment: I have added my 2 cents to update the post a littile bit.Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Never mind @Mr.Frodo, And ORDER BY is good for filtering too...